# Multiprocess synchronization in python

Tags: python, synchronization, multiprocessing

I'm using multimechanize (MM) for performance testing. MM creates multiple processes representing different "users". I need to assign each of these processes with unique (username, password) pair from some set. How should I synchronize this? Should I create a separate process that hands pairs when processes ask it to? This seems excessive, is there a simpler way to do this?

EDIT:
I don't control how these processes are created, MM handles that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `multimechanize/core.py`:

```
# scripts have access to these vars, which can be useful for loading unique data
trans.thread_num = self.thread_num
trans.process_num = self.process_num
```

So every `Transaction()` instance can access its thread id / process id.